# How to setup react-router to work on localhost and deployment URL under path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, webpack-dev-server, react-router-dom

I'm using `webpack-dev-server` to locally host a repo on `localhost:1111`. We have setup Jenkins such that pushing to this repo on any branch is viewable on a url like `jenkins.example.com/repo/branch/`. I'm trying now to setup routing with `react-router`

```
import { Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import createBrowserHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";
const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

and am rendering like

```
<Router history={history}>
  <div>
    <nav>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <Link to="/Example">Example</Link>
    </nav>
    <Route exact path="/" render={Home} />
    <Route path="/Example" render={Example} />
  </div>
</Router>
```

This works on localhost as expected. `localhost:1111/Example` renders `Example`. But `<Link to="/Example">` links to `jenkins.example.com/Example` there. Using `./Example` does not work at all. How can I setup `react-router` such that it continues to work locally as `localhost:1111/Example` but uses a URL like `jenkins.example.com/repo/branch/Example` instead?

Comment: change the binding to use 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost? This is just a guess. Otherwise as part of your webpack build, you'll have to determine your IP and use that to start.

Comment: How do you change the binding? What does that mean?

Comment: Please show your code with `Link` component

Comment: @GProst updated to include the `Link` usage :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<Router>`'s `basename` property to solve this problem. So for your Jenkins server you have to define `basename = '/repo/branch'` and router will work as expected.

But the problem is how you can dynamically set `basename` for your router. Because today you use Jenkins, tomorrow `localhost` and the day after tomorrow it is a production server.

For this particular problem you can use custom environment variable (for instance `MY_APP_ROUTER_BASENAME`) and pass it to the resulting app build via `webpack.DefinePlugin` as follows:

```
// in your webpack.config.js

// get basename from your custom environment variable
const routerBasename = process.env.MY_APP_ROUTER_BASENAME

const config = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    ...
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      process: {
        env: {
          ROUTER_BASENAME: JSON.stringify(routerBasename)
        }
      }
    }),
    ...
  ],
  ...
}

module.exports = config
```

And then in your app codebase you can get this variable like this:

```
// also set default value (for using at localhost for example)
const basename = process.env.ROUTER_BASENAME || '/'

...

<Router history={history} basename={basename}>
  ...
</Router>
```